# SQL IF two IDs are equal then select

Tags: sql, select

I am trying to get correct result but I can not find right way to get.

I have this table:
[image]

I would like to get result like this one

[image]

This is my code:

```
SELECT employee_ID, first_name, manager_id ,
       (SELECT first_name from employees where MANAGER_ID= employee_id)
from employees
```

I got only first 3 columns and fourth one is empty because its wrong select

Comment: Do a `JOIN` instead. (Or a LEFT JOIN.)

Comment: Please include table definition, sample data, and required results as *text* in *the question body*. Having to manually convert images into text is too hard.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Can I do JOIN when its only one table?

Comment: mySQL,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do self join to the same table

```
select emp1.employee_ID, emp1.first_name, emp1.manager_id,emp2.first_name as manager_name from employees emp1
left join employees emp2 
on emp1.manager_id=emp2.employee_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad explanation, I have 5 columns, first one in not in the picture because its only ID of row, my first row is Employee id, second one is first_name, third one is manager id and fourth one should be first name of manager. Manager name is that when manager id is equal to employee id, so e.g. employee id = 206, first name is William, manager id is 205. and name should be Shelley because Shelley's employee ID is 205